# QML runtime environment not found

Tags: qt, runtime, qml, environment

I have QT version 4.7.4 (32 bit).
I am learning QML but don't know how to run it. The website says that QML runtime environment should be provided and it is installed with the QT itself. But there is no QML runtime environment in my computer. How to provide this environment manually?

Comment: "But there is no QML runtime environment in my computer." How have you found out this fact?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need [QML Viewer](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qmlviewer.html):

> The viewer is located at *QTDIR/bin/qmlviewer*. To load a .qml file with the viewer, run the viewer and select the file to be opened, or provide the file path on the command line